# Select Value fetched from mysql

Tags: html

I have a select tag contains option male and female , I'm making an update form but when I load and set value of select (from mysql) it always display the first option which is "Male".

```
 <select value="<?php echo $gender ; ?> name="gender" 
id="gen">
<option > Male </option>
<option > Female </option>

</select>
```

I know there's a javascript way in this case but I can't find the correct one and it's not working. I'm also thinking about if statement comparing $gender to string male or female then if possible I might change attribute of option selected=selected.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the option that is correct to "selected"

A drop-down list with a pre-selected option:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp

So your best bet is to drop the PHP value into Javascript and handle it from there.

Alternatively, if you really want to use just PHP

```
$html = '<select name="gender" id="gen">';
if($gender == "Male") {
  $html .= "<option selected> Male </option>";
  $html .= "<option> Female </option>";
}else{
  $html .= "<option> Male </option>";
  $html .= "<option selected> Female </option>";
}
$html .= "</select>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Yea, how do you write it in javascript ? maybe I just prefer javascript in it because i will put that onload. I tried it once and I'm stuck in how to change elements atrribute syntax or could an option considered as element in javascript or only the select tag?

Comment: var element = document.getElementById('element');

element.value = 'saab';   <---- See original post for reference